# Import from different files node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I trying to use functions from file 1 within file 2, when i run directly from File2.js works well, but when i try to run from File1, i got:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: func1 is not a function

File 1:

```
const { func3 } = require("./File2.js")

function func1();
function func2();

func3(); //ok!

module.exports = {
    func1,
    func2
};
```

File 2:

```
const { func1, func2 } = require("./File1.js")

function func3() {
  func1() //error
  func2() //error
}
module.exports = {
    func3,
};
```

When i call node file 2, i can call func 1, func2 without problems, works well;

But when i run File 1 and call file2(), i got undefined to func1 and func2 within File 1

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: func1 is not a function

Anyone know how to solve it? I've tried change how to require, also remove avoid duplcation, but still didnt found a solution

Answer (score 2):

## Avoid Circular Dependencies

This is the main reason it is best practice to strictly avoid circular dependencies in your code. They're almost never a good idea and the behavior you're seeking can be achieved much cleaner through other means.

To understand the issue, you should know that when you `require` a file, execution of the current file is paused while that new file is executed. This means when the interpreter hits this line:

```
const { func3 } = require("./File2.js")
```

It *pauses* File1.js (before its `module.exports` has been assigned!) and starts executing File2.js immediately. Now, the first line of File2.js is a directive to execute File1.js, which we just came from. The interpreter recognizes that File1 is already mid-execution, so it simply returns the **current value** of `module.exports` - an empty object. Thus, its properties `func1` and `func2` are undefined at that time, and they are never re-assigned.

## Export a Wrapper Function

Circular dependencies are pretty much always unnecessary. If you encounter a situation you think could be solved with a circular dependency, you should reframe your thinking and make the relationship strictly one-way.

To put this very simply: Your File2 needs `func1` and `func2` from File1. That doesn't mean File2 depends on File1. You can simply pass those two functions as arguments to a function exported from File2, and the need for circular dependencies vanishes.

Here's a sample:

File 1:

```
function func1();
function func2();

const { func3 } = require("./File2.js")(func1, func2);

func3(); //ok!
```

File 2:

```
module.exports = function(func1, func2) {
  return {
    func3: function() {
      func1() //ok!
      func2() //ok!
    }
  }
};
```